# java/scala web application and psexec

Tags: java, windows, scala, psexec

I'm developing a webapp that should handle some resources in the filesystem and run some application with privileges of a specific user. Until now I called the ProcessBuilder and the psexec service available with Windows 7 and other version:

```
def get() = {
  var currentOutputLine = ""
  val pb = new ProcessBuilder("psexec.exe", "/ACCEPTEULA", 
  "-u", "user1", "-p", "password", "-w", batchpath,  batchfile)
  pb.directory(new File(batchpath))
  pb.redirectErrorStream(true)
  val proc = pb.start
  val input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream))
while ({
    currentOutputLine = input.readLine();
    currentOutputLine != null
  }) {

}
```

The application server is running as a special user like TOMCATUSER and I'm trying to call a batchfile as "user1". This code works fine with Windows 7 x64, but I have an issue with Windows 2008 sp2.

Using Windows 2008 server sp2, the execution of the psexec from the java application returned a 1073741502 error and watching the eventviewr I can see that the OS reported an error on cmd.exe because is not able to upen the popup window.

After alot of test I found that I have to assign the "user1" and "tomcatuser" to the administrator group in the system where psexec is called, and call the psexec with the hostname parameter like this:

```
def get() = {
  var currentOutputLine = ""
  val pb = new ProcessBuilder("psexec.exe","\\\\localhost", "/ACCEPTEULA", 
  "-u", "user1", "-p", "password", "-w", batchpath,  batchfile)
  pb.directory(new File(batchpath))
  pb.redirectErrorStream(true)
  val proc = pb.start
  val input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream))
while ({
    currentOutputLine = input.readLine();
    currentOutputLine != null
  }) {

}
```

Is there a way to avoid this issue? I don't want to assign administrator privileges to the user1 account, because I only need to run a script as user1. I use psexec because I mainly need to work in the filesystem as "user1" and not as tomcatuser (create, copy, move files), is there a better and safe solution to do this?

Thanks million.

Flavio

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using winrs/winrm provided by windows 2008

I configured the winrm server and after that the client code is:

```
def get() = {
 var currentOutputLine = ""
 val pb = new ProcessBuilder("winrs.exe", "-r:http://localhost:5985", "-u:user1", "-p:password",
 "-ad","-d:workingpath","\""+commandtorun+"\"")

 pb.directory(new File(batchpath))
 pb.redirectErrorStream(true)
 val proc = pb.start
 val input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream))
 while ({
   currentOutputLine = input.readLine();
   currentOutputLine != null
 }) {

}
```